# Can I capture variable outside of block like closure of other language in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

```
defmodule Test do
  use Retry
  import Stream

  def call_service(count) do
    IO.puts "call_service #{count}"
    %{"errors" => true}
  end

  def hello do
    count = 0
    retry_while with: linear_backoff(500, 1) |> take(5) do
      count = count + 1 # incorrect !!!
      call_service(count)
      |> case do
        result = %{"errors" => true} -> {:cont, result}
        result -> {:halt, result}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Above example is referenced from retry module's [document](https://hexdocs.pm/retry/Retry.html#:%7E:text=retry_while%20with%3A%20linear_backoff(500%2C%201)%20%7C%3E%20take(5)%20do%0A%20%20call_service%0A%20%20%7C%3E%20case%20do%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20%25%7B%22errors%22%20%3D%3E%20true%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%3Acont%2C%20result%7D%0A%20%20%20%20result%20-%3E%20%7B%3Ahalt%2C%20result%7D%0A%20%20end%0Aend).

What I want to do here is knowing count value in call_service function. As you may be already notice, the example does not work as I expected.

Can I have count value indicates how many time the function is called in call_service function?

Comment: it's helpful if you include what result you got vs. what result you expected.  I'm not familiar with `Retry`, but it looks like it's using some macros, which have their own restrictions on syntax because of their compile-time execution.  The docs seem to be missing a few critical bits of information, such as showing what exactly the "atoms" the service call should return.

Comment: FWIW, I have [provided a PR](https://github.com/safwank/ElixirRetry/pull/42) to the original repo introducing `reduce_while/3` to support the accumulator passing through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot assign a variable "outside of [its] block" -- this is part of what it means when you hear that "in Elixir, everything is an assignment".  The common pattern of

```
# pseudo-code
x = 0
for y in z {
  # do something
  x = x + 1
}
```

does NOT work in Elixir.  Instead, you frequently need to rely on map and reduce functions (often provided by the [Enum](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) module).

Consider this simple module that relies on `Enum` to repeatedly call a function.  Here we use a guard clause to limit the number of calls we actually make, even though we are enumerating over a larger range.

```
defmodule Foo do
  def repeat do
    Enum.each(1..10, fn n ->
      call_service(n)
    end)
  end

  defp call_service(count) when count > 7 do
    IO.puts("Whoops... called too many times!")
    {:error, "Called too many times"}
  end

  defp call_service(count) do
    IO.puts("Count is #{count}")
    {:ok, "Called the service!"}
  end
end
```

If we run this code by executing `Foo.repeat()`, we see output like the following:

```
Count is 1
Count is 2
Count is 3
Count is 4
Count is 5
Count is 6
Count is 7
Whoops... called too many times!
Whoops... called too many times!
Whoops... called too many times!
```

This shows that we enumerated over the entire range of numbers (1-10), but we performed some different action when the count was greater than 7.

More commonly, when you want to re-assign a number during the course of a "loop", you will end up using `Enum.map/2` or `Enum.reduce/3`.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing Retry, I don't think you can achieve your desired results with `retry_while`. However, you can use the DelayStreams with a simple `Enum.reduce_while/2` that tracks a count as illustrated by the following example.

```
defmodule World do
  def call_service(count, limit) do
    IO.inspect(count, label: "count")
    cond do
      limit == 7 -> %{errors: true}
      count == limit -> %{errors: false}
      true -> %{errors: true}
    end
  end

  def hello(limit) do
    50
    |> Retry.DelayStreams.linear_backoff(1)
    |> Enum.take(limit * 2)
    |> Enum.reduce_while(0, fn delay, count ->
      Process.sleep(delay)
      case call_service(count, limit) do
        %{errors: false} = success -> {:halt, {:ok, success}}
        error when count == limit -> {:halt, {:error, error}}
        _ -> {:cont, count + 1}
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

with these results:

```
iex(9)> World.hello 3
count: 0
count: 1
count: 2
count: 3
{:ok, %{errors: false}}
iex(10)> World.hello 7
count: 0
count: 1
count: 2
count: 3
count: 4
count: 5
count: 6
count: 7
{:error, %{errors: true}}
iex(11)>
```